# Restricting user to NOT input decimal

Tags: c#

Hi I'm new in C# i just want to ask if this is possible? How to not allow the user to input decimal in console app in c#

Comment: You might want to rethink the goal here - instead of define what input you do not to take in, define what input you do want to take in. Usually, it's a much shorter list and therefor much easier. You should also be aware of the fact that anything the user enters via Console is actually a string, and it's your responsibility, as the programmer, to convert that string into whatever type you actually want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a method to restrict the user from entering some characters in the console, but I have a mechanism for you to overcome the issues that you are facing.

You can make use of `.TryParse()` method of the type you are dealing with. The [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation succeeded. you can depend on that return value to check for valid inputs.

If you have to consider culture-specific conversion, you can make use of the [overloaded method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Int32__) which accepts NumberStyles and IFormatProvider

Consider that you are dealing with integers, then your code will be like the following:

```
string inputStr="12.36";
int convertedValue=0;
if(int.TryParse(inputStr,out convertedValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for correct input");
    // proceed with your code with the converted value in convertedValue
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either use [`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8) to read a whole line or [`Console.ReadKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.8) to get single key strokes.

Using `Console.ReadLine` gives you every character, the user enters before pressing return. You have no control, what characters the users enters.

If you implement an user interaction using `Console.ReadKey` you can ignore every character the user is not allowed to type in and put a string together using all the characters you get.